# error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python

I was building a simple client/server code and i keep getting this error. I dont understand why (I am trying to get used to python). here is my code:

*Server Code*:

```
import socket
from socket import*
from time import ctime

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR =(HOST, PORT)

tcpsersock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsersock.bind(ADDR)
tcpsersock.listen(5)

while True:
    print("waiting for connection...")
    tcpclisock, addr = tcpsersock.accpet()
    print("...Connected from: "),addr

    while True:
        data = tcpclisock.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if not data:
            break
        tcpclisock.send('[%s] %s' %(ctime(), data))

    tcpclisock.close()
tcpsersock.close()
```

*Client Code*:

```
import socket
from socket import*
from time import ctime

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpclisock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpclisock.connect(ADDR)

while True:
    data = raw_input('> ')
    if not data:
        break
    tcpclisock.send(data)
    data = tcpclisock.recv(BUFSIZ)
    if not data:
        break
    print data

tcpclisock.close()
```

I get this error:

```
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: hey, you are still writing `accpet()` instead of `accept()`!

Comment: I am getting `AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'accpet'` from your code.

Comment: Fixed that, I just wrote this question on top of the previous one. There was a suggestion about firewall problem, however i closed all security programs

Comment: I get the error after fixing "accept" if you use the client and server as the same machine and run the code, you would get the error.

Comment: I am not sure what to do next. This is my first attempt at server programming

Comment: You are running both programs on the same machine? What does `netstat -a` say, when you have the server running?

Comment: perhaps you should bind `'localhost'` on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tcpclisock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

This is almost straight from the documents page for socket which you can find here [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example)

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no server process running on the server side (due to `accpet()`?)

Answer (score 0):

That suggests the remote machine has received your connection request, and send back a refusal (a RST packet). I don't think this is a case of the remote machine simply not having a process listening on that port (but i could be wrong!).

That sounds like a firewall problem. It could be a firewall on the remote machine, or a filter in the network in between, or, perhaps on your local machine - are you running any kind of security software locally?

Comment: Yes I am running Norton and there is windows firewall

Comment: This is exactly what happens when there's no process listening on that port.

Comment: any suggestions on how I could fix this?

Comment: I am not sure what to do next. This is my first attempt at server programming

Answer (score 0):

first run the server script -- which starts listening
then open the client ..
or -- try to change the port 
the error simply indicates "that no one is listening"